# Reset/reprovision the operating system of a virtual machine in Azure?

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, cloud, virtual

I want to know that can we reset/reprovision the operating system of a virtual machine in Azure?
For example, let's say I created a ubuntu virtual machine, installed docker and some more stuff on it.
Now I want to just get the factory ubuntu environment (the factory installation which was before installing docker and stuff).
Is it possible?
(I don't want to delete and recreate the VM).
I explored a lot but couldn't found any way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the VM Backup and create a backup at the point that you do not install the docker and stuff. Then restores the VM to the point via the backup. If you do not create the backup, then you cannot restore the VM. The only thing you can do is to delete and recreate the VM to get the factory ubuntu environment. Take a look at the [Azure VM Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-introduction) to understand how does it work.

Comment: Ok, it means that reprovisioning is not supported directly in Azure. :( Actually I don't want to use backup as I'm just trying out Azure and backups are paid feature :(